# How to download all shared media files from a telegram group?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

There is a telegram group with more than 40,000 shared files in it.
Is there any bot to download all of them all at once? If not is there any telegram api script method using python to download shared media files?

Answer (score 9):

You can use [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon), a Telegram client to download all the files in a public group:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from tqdm import tqdm
# These example values won't work. You must get your own api_id and
# api_hash from `my.telegram.org` , under API Development.
api_id = APIID
api_hash = 'APIHASH'
client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()
print(client.get_me().stringify())
# client.send_message('username', 'Hello! Talking to you from Telethon')
# client.send_file('username', '/home/myself/Pictures/holidays.jpg')
# client.download_profile_photo('vic')
messages = client.get_messages('intothestates', limit=2000)
print(len(messages))
for msg in tqdm(messages):
    client.download_media(msg)
```

Comment: Here is the video tutorial for how to do it with Telethon - https://youtu.be/J5H_gRdPJSU

Answer (score 6):

It seems [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) has changed since victorvs' answer. ([Docs](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/index.html))

this should work:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events
from tqdm import  tqdm
import os

# These example values won't work. You must get your own api_id and
# api_hash from https://my.telegram.org, under API Development.
api_id = <api_id>
api_hash = '<api_hash>'


with TelegramClient('name', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    messages = client.get_messages('<channel/chat>', limit=50) # limit defaults to 1
    for msg in tqdm(messages):
        msg.download_media(file=os.path.join('media', '<file_name>'))
```

Answer (score 3):

The telegram bot api unfortunately doesn't allow viewed old messages (or files).

The only way to do this is using an API such as [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon), which acts as a user as far as telegram is concerned.